# ASP.NET Web Application Desgin Tool

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

i have an ASP.NET WebApplication which i have uploaded to hosting site. I shifted control of site to client, so they can customize aspx pages and change the style of site.

My Question is that, is there any Free tool that can be used to manipulate aspx pages along with preview of that page? Site also has master page too.

Please share the link if you know any. I also googled and found few tools. they are either paid, or they doesn't have live preview of site.

Thanks

Comment: web matrix ? http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-express-products) but it is only for technical people, I wouldn't recommend it for anyone non-technical unless the changes they need to make are quite simple.

The "preview of site" as you call it, makes me wonder whether you are expecting to find a tool that will preview changes in the aspx files before saving them, which sounds a bit sci-fi to me...

Comment: preview of page, on which i am making changes. lol my bad. thanks. As my client is non-technical, so i am looking for the tool. this is the reason i didn't recommended VS Express. BTW thanks for the link. i have send recommendation of webmatrix tool suggested by @adt in comment of question. If it won't work with client then i will suggest VS Express. Thanks Again sir